# Modifying Slug on FeedMe Import

Tags: craft3, plugins, plugin-feedme, modules

I have the following Module loaded into my system, following the Event's on the FeedMe documentation I've implemented the following to change the slug per entry import but unfortunately, it's returning a strange error that I just can't fix.

Here's the module:

```
<?php

namespace modules;

use Craft;

use craft\feedme\base\Element;
use craft\feedme\events\ElementEvent;
use craft\feedme\services\Process;
use craft\feedme\events\FeedProcessEvent;


use yii\base\Event;

use craft\helpers\ElementHelper;
use craft\elements\Category;
use craft\elements\Entry;

class TitleChangerModule extends Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        Event::on(
          Process::class,
          Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE,
          function(FeedProcessEvent $event) {
            switch($event->feed['name']){
                case 'merchants':
                    $element = $event->element;
                    $element->slug = ElementHelper::createSlug($element->title.' '.'Coupon Codes & Promo Codes');
                    break;
            }
        });
    } // Close Public Function
} // Close Module Off
```

It returns the following error on each import via the feedme logs.

> Class 'craft\feedme\base\ElementEvent' not found - Element.php: 58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a PR](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/pull/566) to fix this, in the meantime, you can add `use craft\feedme\events\ElementEvent;` at the top of `vendor/craftcms/feed-me/src/base/Element.php`

Comment: Thanks Oli, annoying little bug this one!